# What is the different between the merge tag and the append tag in the Struts2?

Tags: struts2, tags

I reading the Struts 2 Tutorial  in link http://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/struts_control_tags.htm.

But in the chapter : Struts 2 Control Tags
I look at feature of them the same, so i do not understand the different between the merge tag and the append tag in this tutorial.

Please explain to me be clear!

(Src)

**The merge tag:**

These merge tag take two or more lists as parameters and merge them all together as shown below:

```
<s:merge var="myMergedIterator">
     <s:param value="%{myList1}" />
     <s:param value="%{myList2}" />
     <s:param value="%{myList3}" />
</s:merge>
<s:iterator value="%{#myMergedIterator}">
     <s:property />
</s:iterator>
```

**The append tag:**

These append tag take two or more lists as parameters and append them all together as shown below:

```
<s:append var="myAppendIterator">
     <s:param value="%{myList1}" />
     <s:param value="%{myList2}" />
     <s:param value="%{myList3}" />
</s:append>
<s:iterator value="%{#myAppendIterator}">
     <s:property />
</s:iterator>
```

Comment: http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/merge.html and http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/append.html have very explicit examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are almost the same except for the way elements are combined together.

- `Append Tag` - appends the values one after the other
- `Merge Tag` - weaves the values of the lists

For example, if you have 3 Lists like this:

- `myList1 : a, b, c, d`
- `myList2 : 1, 2, 3, 4`
- `myList3 : A, B, C, D`

Using `Append` would result in this:

- `a, b, c, d, 1, 2, 3, 4, A, B, C, D`
  (All of the values from the same list are adjacent. The lists have been placed one after other.)

Using `Merge` would result in this:

- `a, 1, A, b, 2, B, c, 3, C, d, 4, D`
  (The lists have been weaved together taking one element each from the list at a time. In case one of the list is shorter, the remaining elements of the longer list will be placed towards the end post weaving)